# File structure for dev server and repo

Tags: php, git, codeigniter, filesystems

I have a development server at dev.mysite.com and I am working with coda and git to make commits and pushes to the repo which has a developmenet branch that points to my dev domain.

The file structure as of right now is this. As of right now does anyone see anything that I should reconsider changing. I'm asking this because of having a public_html inside the dev folder or what. With this setup currently when I load dev.mysite.com it shows the index of / which shows .gitignore, .git, and public_html.

```
../
    /dev
        /mysite.com
            .git
            .gitignore
            /application
            /public_html
                /assets
                index.php
            /system
        /mysecondsite.com
    /application
    /public_html
        /assets
        /index.php
    /system
    /sites
        /mysecondsite.com
            /application
            /system
            index.php
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Thank you for the edit I was trying to figure out which would be acceptable tags.

Comment: You should change the doc root of your site to the public_html folder

Comment: Is that done in my htaccess? If so what is it that I need to do that.

Comment: You can deny access to these files/folders with htaccess - you can't change the doc root (the site example.com points at this folder on my server) with a .htaccess file.

Comment: I'm sorry I"m not understanding what you said. Could you try and rephrase that for me.

Comment: [no](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#documentroot) :)

Comment: Why can't you rephrase it?

Comment: Because if you don't know what a document root is - you need interactive help and that's not what comments are for. Read the reference, or look for an appropriate place to get help (irc, [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/), some web-dev forum, etc.)

Comment: its also worth saying, knowing the structure of the server he is on, that the dev folder is defined through the httpd.conf as a virtualhost, that the `dev` folder in this instance is the equivalent of the `public_html`, the `public_html` in the above structure was manually added in, with the thought of it being relevant and or needed

Comment: or as AD7six put it.. the document root..

Comment: On another note, Kevin, if your going to look for help with structures and what not, ya might want to emphasis the whole scenario a bit more, causes less confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a development environment and a production environment. While having the core files for CI outside of a public_html. You have to redefine your document root. I assume you are using a server the comes with cPanel as your means of administration for your server.

So that said, you go into your cpanel and where you defined your `dev` subdomain, you should be able to edit the document root folder. So on the server in your dev folder you will add a public_html like I gather you already have from the example above. And with your current folder settings for dev you add `/public_html` to the string that is the folder path now.

Once you do that allow a minute or two for it to delegate to the server from cPanel. And move your folders around as you see fit.

From there, you find the root index.php and open that up, find the references for your application folder and your system folder and change them to match the paths they should be looking for now. Likely using relative paths.. ie: `../../applications` for example. Save your index.php

Assuming you have done everything in general correct your copy of CI should load correctly as it did when you didnt have everything in the folders split up like you want..